# Is it possible to stack Yacc grammar rule code?

Tags: c++, c, parsing, yacc, bison

Lets say I need to run some initialization code everytime I match a rule how can I reduce the redundancy?

```
rule : TOKEN1 { init(); token1Code(); }
     | TOKEN2 { init(); token2Code(); }
     ;
```

Also is it possible to do something like

```
rule : TOKEN1
     | TOKEN2
     { codeForToken1OrToken2(); }
     ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
rule : { init(); } real_rule { codeForToken1or2(); } ;

real_rule : TOKEN1 { token1Code(); }
          | TOKEN2 { token2Code(); }
          ;
```

But this may introduce conflicts, depending on how 'rule' is used.

Comment: this grammar is not the same as DevDevDev posted

Comment: The original grammar that you posted wasn't the same language. Now, you have corrected the error

Comment: By the way, a grammar doesn't ACCEPT a language. What it does is to GENERATE a language. Only automatons accepts languages.

Answer (score 0):

Since this will really work:

```
rule : TOKEN1 { getToken(); init(); token1Code(); }
     | TOKEN2 { getToken(); init(); token2Code(); }
     ;
```

where **getToken();** is the name of the function that matches the next token in the input (I don't remember the name of the function), you could put a call to some **init();** inside it.

Comment: You don't seem to be answering the question.